# JWT and react, where react gets information from the token

Tags: reactjs, jwt

The question is as follows. After entering data into registration/login form, react sends request to server, in response it gets jwt-token and puts it into localStorage. But how react interacts with the token further, react needs to decrypt the token? For example when I want to get the user's role, which is put into the token, and respectively render pages depending on the role, to do this I need to get the data from the token. Again, to get this data the token is decrypted on the client side?(react)

Comment: Please try to elaborate further what you want and what you've done, preferably with code examples. But in short React itself has nothing to do with JWT's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send a request back to the server with the JWT token and let the server decrypt it and then do whatever you want with the info, you should not decrypt tokens in the client side for security reasons, if you want to get the user role, make a request to the server which retrieves the current user roles and use JWT to get the current user info and also use it as an authorization method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can I ask another question, that is, it is better not to store information about the user in the react, even email or role, right?

Comment: short answer is no, it is bad practice and a security problem as JWT tokens can be easily decrypted and it should not contain any [PII (personally identifiable information)](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/legacy/sp/nistspecialpublication800-122.pdf)

Comment: You mean react by "it," right?

Comment: yes, i mean react, or the client side, whatever makes more sense for you :)

Comment: Much thx for the answer <3

Comment: @Kakiz Tbh, it partially make sense. First and foremost the data present in the jwt can public, and it's not a security concern to read it. If the client tries to modify the payload, than the signature of the jwt will change and the back-end will fail to validate it against the secret, which will result in a unauthorized response. You should take into consideration the reasons behind encryption, it might not be needed.